# Is there a name for the function that gives me the signal of a number only?

Tags: functions, terminology

I know the function that gives the absolute value of a number is called either absolute function or 'modulus' function, such as:
$$
modulus(-6) = modulus(6) = 6
$$
Now, I want to name a function that gives me a unit value with the same signal as the input number, like this:

$$
function(-6) = -1
$$
$$
function(6) = 1
$$

Then I can do this:
$$
modulus(-6) \times function(-6) = -6
$$
I could just call it `signal(x)` but I'd like to know if there is a name for this function.

Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's that signum function.
Actually:
$$\text{signum}(x)=\begin{cases}\begin{align}1,\quad x>0\\0,\quad x=0\\-1,\quad x<0\end{align}\end{cases}$$
See it at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) or [WolframMathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sign.html).

Comment: I have also seen it called the sign function.

Comment: @Ross not sure, but most probably `sign` is short form of `signum`

Comment: Sign is plain English, signum is Latin (but also used in English).

Comment: It's also called the "sign" function, but that will get confused with the "sine" function.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly it. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's called the [Sign function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function), also called the Signum function:

$$\large \text{sgn}(x) = 
\begin{cases} \frac{d}{dx} \left| x\right| =  \frac{x}{\left| x\right|} , \text{when } x \neq0\\
0\space, \text{when} \space x=0
\end{cases} $$

[image: sgn] $\leftarrow$ It is clearly a piecewise step function.

Comment: it's undefined for $\mathtt 0$

Comment: @Aditya: Fixed it. Any more problems?

Comment: $\frac0{|0|}=?$

Comment: @Aditya: Buddy, did you at all see my edit? $\frac{0}{0}$ is an indeterminate, I know. Do you want me to put $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{\left| x\right|}$ instead of zero in definition inorder to make it more complicated looking? I don't see your point in asking me that.

Comment: @Aditya $f(0)$ is defined to be $0$.

Comment: Yes saw that upvoted